# PHP: bad phone number keeps email from me

Tags: php, text, phone-number

I'm trying to get customer's information to be emailed to me through this form, but if the phone number isn't typed in completely together without dashes or parentheses, it gets lost in outer space.  Is there a way to make this into a text-only field so that if it is entered in any way, it will still be emailed to me?  Thanks for your help, Drew

```
<?
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$ToEmail = "mrkuespert@hotmail.com";
$ToSubject = "Message from Island Photo Booths";

$EmailBody =   "Name: $name\n 
                Email: $email\n
                Phone: $phone\n
                City: $city\n
                Message: $message\n";

$Message = $EmailBody;


$headers .= "Content-type: text; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$name." / ".$email."\r\n";

mail($ToEmail,$ToSubject,$Message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Is this a complete example? I don't see any validation, or anything that would prevent the e-mail from being sent due to an improperly formatted phone number.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  I'll need to keep investigating then.  Must be another file I'm missing somewhere.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't there a JavaScript part in the web page preventing a POST of the form data?

Comment: Use the browser debug features to see if the data is POSTed

Comment: Check your server's error logs.

Comment: The code shown does not cause the issue